# Joda - DateTimeFormat - switching position of "MM" and "dd" depending on default Locale

Tags: java, android, jodatime, datetime-format

I have LocalDate, and I want to print the date with day/month as 2 digit, full year and '-' as separator.

Of course I can use sth like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
dtf.print(localDate);
```

and it shows:

```
17-09-2012
18-09-2012
19-09-2012
```

But this is OK only for my Locale, what with the others? For example USA should be:

```
09-17-2012
09-18-2012
09-19-2012
```

How to do this?

There is

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.shortDate();
```

which switches position of day and month by itself.
But it only prints:

```
(my locale):
17/9/12
18/9/12
19/9/12
(USA locale):
9/17/12
9/18/12
9/19/12
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [DateTimeFormatter  API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> // print using the defaults (default locale, chronology/zone of the datetime)
>    String dateStr = formatter.print(dt);
>    // print using the French locale
>    String dateStr = formatter.withLocale(Locale.FRENCH).print(dt);
>    // print using the UTC zone
>    String dateStr = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).print(dt);

So, you can use a Locale or a DateTimeZone with you DateTimeFormatter.

However, since a pattern is set, the output will still be the same.

You could define your `DateTimeFormatter` using a style instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forStyle("M-");
```

and print it with the Locale.

Comment: Yes, I can read API :) But this is not the answer.
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dtf.withLocale(Locale.US).print(localDate)
This will still show
    17-09-2012
but not
    09-17-2012

Comment: @AppiDevo I'm sorry, you are right. This doesn't help with a pattern. I'm doing some further testing. Can you use DateTimeFormat#forStyle or do you need a special pattern?

Comment: @AppiDevo You pretty much have to pick whether you want control over patterns (and write them all yourself), or automatic localisation (and have to stick to standard patterns). I've never heard of an API that would let you combine the two.

Comment: @Katja Christiansen DateTimeFormat.forStyle("M-") is the same as DateTimeFormat.shortDate();
                              

I found the solution, but we can't be sure it will work with every Locale.
String ourPattern = DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("S-", Locale.getDefault());
Now we change in ourPattern: M on MM, d on dd, yy on yyyy and / on - .
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(ourPattern);